# If $M\subset M(n,K)$ is a commuting set of matrices, then $M$ is trigonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to prove the statement:

> If $M\subset M(n,K)$ is a commuting set of matrices, then $M$ is simultaneously trigonalizable. (I imagine $K$ must be algebraically closed)

Now Humphreys - Linear Algebraic Groups - page 100 - says he proceeds by induction on $n$. Let $V=K^n$.

So for the base case, we have $M\subset M(1,K)$, acting on $V=K$. Now either $M=\{0\}$ or $M$ consists of scalar $1\times 1$ matrices, which are diagonal, so base case is done.

Now for the inductive hypothesis, we assume that for $M\subset M(n-1,K)$, a commuting set of matrices, that $M$ is trigonalizable.

How do I use the inductive hypothesis on the case of $M\subset M(n,K)$? He says apply the induced action of $M$ on $V/Kv_1$, where $Kv_1$ is $M$-stable. Am I making the identification of $M\subset M(n,K)$ with a corresponding subset of $M(n-1,K)$, triagonalizing this, and then extending to all of $V$?

Comment: What is $v_1$? Is $K$ algebraically closed?

Comment: What if $M$ contains just a single matrix? Then it is clearly a commuting set, but the element of $M$ need not be trigonalizable over $K$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Every matrix is trigonalizable over an algebraically closed field

Comment: OK, I understand. So the statement "$M$ is trigonalizable" means that one transformation trigonalizes all the members of $M$ simultaneously. Edit: I see Wikipedia uses the term _simultaneously triangularizable_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can decompose $V$ as $Kv_1 \oplus V/Kv_1$. Assuming $Kv_1$ is $M$-stable, then every $A \in M$ descends to a well-defined linear transformation on $V/Kv_1$.

What can you say about the matrix of a linear transformation $T$ of a direct sum $V \oplus W$ where both $V$ and $W$ are $T$-stable?

I think the difficult part here is proving that such a stable line exists, which I assume is in your book. If you don't want to prove the existence of such a line, you can also note that for $A,B \in M$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ preserve each others eigenspaces.